# Constructor con constantes POO. Java

Tags: java, poo, constructor, constantes

tengo una duda sobre un pequeño codigo que he visto. En un ejercicio, creando una clase Electrodomestico, se pide crear una serie de atributos (precio,color,consumo,peso) y que por defecto, el color sera blanco, el consumo energético sera F, el precioBase es de 100 € y el peso de 5 kg (usando constantes).

```
//Constantes
protected final static String COLOR_DEF="blanco";
protected final static char CONSUMO_ENERGETICO_DEF='F';
protected final static double PRECIO_BASE_DEF=100;
protected final static double PESO_DEF=5;
```

Entonces al ver la solucion he visto esto:

```
//Constructor por defecto
public Electrodomestico(){
    this(PRECIO_BASE_DEF, PESO_DEF, CONSUMO_ENERGETICO_DEF, COLOR_DEF);
}
```

La cuestion es que no entiendo que hace este ultimo constructor, ademas cuando lo copio en Eclipse me da error porque me dice que el constructor no está definido..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este último constructor está invocando otro constructor (ya que esto se hace por medio de `this();`, y al ingresarle los parámetros estarías indicándole que le asigne esos valores a los atributos correspondientes.

Al ver el código que nos muestras, podemos deducir dos cosas:

La primera es que tienes una clase llamada `Electrodomestico` el cuál posee (además de las cuatro variables estáticas) 4 variables para definir el color, el consumo energético, el precio base y el peso. Algo como esto:

```
// Atributos de la clase
private String color;
private char consumo_energetico;
private double precio_base;
private double peso;
```

Lo segundo que se puede deducir es que tienes (o debes tener) un segundo constructor con los parámetros de clase para cada variable de la clase (mostrados anteriormente). Finalmente, tu clase debería verse algo así:

```
public class Electrodomestico {

    //Constantes
    protected final static String COLOR_DEF="blanco";
    protected final static char CONSUMO_ENERGETICO_DEF='F';
    protected final static double PRECIO_BASE_DEF=100;
    protected final static double PESO_DEF=5; 

    // Atributos de la clase
    private String color;
    private char consumo_energetico;
    private double precio_base;
    private double peso;

    //Constructor por defecto
    public Electrodomestico() {
        this(PRECIO_BASE_DEF, PESO_DEF, CONSUMO_ENERGETICO_DEF, COLOR_DEF);
    }

    public Electrodomestico(String color, char consumo_energetico, double precio_base, double peso) {
        this.color = color;
        this.consumo_energetico = consumo_energetico;
        this.precio_base = precio_base;
        this.peso = peso;
    }

    // Aquí va más código, GETTERS y SETTERS... 
}
```

De esta manera, al utilizar `this(PRECIO_BASE_DEF, PESO_DEF, CONSUMO_ENERGETICO_DEF, COLOR_DEF);` estarías llamando al segundo constructor y asignándole los valores por defecto, dándonos como resultado un nuevo objeto electrodoméstico con las características por defecto.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu rapida respuesta, y no hace falta que los parametros PRECIO_BASE_DEF, etc.. esten ordenados en el this() igual que como en el segundo constructor?

Comment: Sí, obligatoriamente deben estar exactamente en el mismo orden que en el segundo constructor. Si necesitas cambiar el orden, entonces cambia el orden en el segundo constructor

Comment: Pero sí o sí deben coincidir lo parámetros del constructor, con las variables que le ingresas

Comment: gracias. Y ya lo ultimo, si quisiera escribir el constructor por defecto sin usar el this(), sería no pasarle nada por parametro y hacer this.color = COLOR_DEF    etc no?

Comment: Así es, tendrías que hacer eso con cada variable. Y así eliminas el segundo constructor (pero  eso implica tener que eliminar `this(PRECIO_BASE_DEF, PESO_DEF, CONSUMO_ENERGETICO_DEF, COLOR_DEF);`) si no te seguirá marcando `constructor no definido` (quiere decir que no existe tal constructor)

Comment: sí entiendo, muchas gracias. Un saludo!

Comment: Con gusto, @Traxomax. :-)